# Compiling Assembly dll in c#

Tags: c#, dll

So after looking around for the last ~2 hours, I have been able to figure out how I can do everything I need to do with a given assembly. My current problem is, I want to actually compile an assembly from the source code, to make my application more user friendly. I could make the user compile a .dll, but I think it would be nicer if I would handle that myself.
No matter where I look, I always end up needing to use the [CSharpCodeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.-ctor?view=net-5.0). This would be totally fine, if it wasn't for the fact, that this class does not exist in the version of C# / .net I am using ([A screenshot of my Rider project settings as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ezoS.png)).

Since I am at the very beginning of my project, I am not sure if it is smarter to change the language/framework version or to keep looking for a new solution.

As a second reference, this is the Method I am trying to fill in:

```
public static Assembly GenerateAssembly(Uri assemblySourceUri)
{
        
}
```

Any help with this matter is greatly appreciated.

Edit: To clarify: This is gonna be used for plugins and no, I don't really care about how this problem would be solved best without compiling the .dll at runtime or why I most likely won't need to compile it at runtime, I simply want to know how I can compile a .dll at runtime. This is partially because I want to figure out how everything in C# works.

Comment: User compile a dll? does not sound right

Comment: @T.S. I am coding my own application and want to support plugins with custom functions and since I personally don't like lua, I wanted to do it with C#, but I need to figure out how to compile assemblies for that to work

Comment: Please fix your question I don't see word "plugin" in it

Comment: If your plugin interface uses C# .dll's then of course the user will compile it themselves on their development environment.... you dont need to worry about that, all you need to figure out how your interface looks like and behaves and how you actually dynamically load your plugins ...

Comment: @Tomek Even so, I like to build features nobody really needs, because it makes the whole project more interesting to me. So while you are technically correct about me not needing this for this specific use case, I am still interested as to how this could be achieved.

Comment: I suggest you look into Roslyn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out, the solution is just as simple as I hoped it would be:
While System.CodeDom exists by default, most things only exist once you add the NuGet package "System.CodeDom"